# Python Subprocess Security

Tags: python, subprocess

I understand why using 'shell=True' can be a security risk if you have untrusted input.  However, I don't understand how 'shell=False' avoids the same risks.

Presumably if I wanted to allow a user to provide an input he might input: var="rm -rf /"

My code might simply:

```
subprocess.call(var,shell=True) # bad stuff
```

Or I might do:

```
varParts=var.split()
subprocess.call(varParts,shell=False) # also bad, right?
```

It would seem that the assumption is one wouldn't go through the trouble of processing the input as I did in the second example and therefore this would/could not happen?

Comment: ummmm any time you are passing untrusted input as a call you are running significant risks .... where did you hear shell = False makes it safe? http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments ... all it does is stop shell injection which is just one attack ...

Comment: The very link you provided has a note that says "Warning:
Invoking the system shell with shell=True can be a security hazard if combined with untrusted input."  That implies to me that using shell=False provides some defense against that.

Comment: It is worth noting that you should use shlex.split rather than str.split methods as shlex will properly handle escaping in quotes and spaces

Answer (score 19):

With `shell=False`, the `args[0]` is the program to be executed and `args[1:]` are passed as arguments to this program.

So, for example,

```
subprocess.call(['cat','nonexistent;','rm','-rf'])
```

calls the `cat` program and sends the 3 strings `'nonexistent;'`,`'rm'`,`'-rf'` as arguments to `cat`. This is perfectly safe, though invalid since `-r` is an invalid option to `cat`.

However, arbitrary user input could still be unsafe. If, for example, you were to allow the user to control the program to be called, as in

```
subprocess.call(['rm','-rf'])
```

Comment: That's good information.  So I guess the use case for user input would be to allow a user to 'complete' a predefined command but not to 'provide' one. I am using an XML file to provide some shell command which allows me to test that some arbitrary condition is met within the operating system.  The command could possibly be a string of commands piped together.  This makes it difficult to read and execute the command with 'shell=False'.  I was just wondering if shell=False provided some intrinsic defense against dangerous commands like 'rm -rf /'.

Comment: If the XML is specifying the command to be run, then executing `subprocess.call` is inherently dangerous. Perhaps you could run the script as a [user with limited privileges](http://askubuntu.com/questions/253027/how-to-sandbox-bash-shell-to-affect-only-current-directory).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Did I understand correctly? As long as the program (first element of list, `'cat'` in your example) is NOT user supplied, it is safe to use arbitrary user input in the other elements of the list.