# Mailx won't send through python

Tags: python, subprocess, mailx

I'm rewriting a shell script to python and a part of it includes sending notifications via mailx.
I can't seem to get the subprocess right.

`result = subprocess.run(["/bin/mailx", "-r", "sender@email.com", "-s", "Test", "recipient@email.com"], check=True)`

When I run this on the server the command returns a blank row, "won't complete" and I thought it might be because mailx is waiting for the email body because when I try sending through bash without a body I get sort of the same problem, so I got these tips:

1.
`result = subprocess.run(["echo", "Testing", "|", /bin/mailx", "-r", "sender@email.com", "-s", "Test", "recipient@email.com"], check=True)` and
2. `result = subprocess.run(["/bin/mailx", "-r", "sender@email.com", "-s", "Test", "recipient@email.com", b"Testingtesting"], check=True)`

When testing 1, it just echoes out everything after echo.
When testing 2, I get the blank row again.

Comment: Have you tried `subprocess.check_output()` for your `mailx` command?

Comment: Same thing, the script won't complete and I have to ctrl+c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `subprocess.Popen` you can do it as below :

```
import subprocess
cmd = """
        echo 'Message Body' | mailx -s 'Message Title' -r sender@someone.com receiver@example.com 
      """

result = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, errors = result.communicate()
```

Regarding `shell=True` from [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments)

> shell=False disables all shell based features, but does not suffer from this vulnerability; see the Note in the Popen constructor documentation for helpful hints in getting shell=False to work.
> The use of shell=True is strongly discouraged in cases where the command string is constructed from external input

In your case, if you are not taking user input to pass it to `subprocess.Popen` you are safe.

Comment: I read that you want to avoid shell = True due to security reasons, and that subprocess.run or call is preferred to Popen, this is in a production environment hence my caution.

Comment: It worked, but can anyone explain what untrusted input means exactly?
"Invoking the system shell with shell=True can be a security hazard if combined with untrusted input."

Comment: With the reference to [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009416/python-subprocess-security), you can do `shell=False` it will provide some security.

Comment: I tried shell=False anti returned a bunch of errors. 
But in my case I'm writing scripts so no user input will be allowed, this will run and compare files to send warnings through mailx. So in my case it is safe?

Comment: so in this case you can use `shell=True`. I will update the answer after more digging into this.